# Android Studio: how to setup generated Cloud Endpoints sources?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, gradle, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

I built a Cloud Endpoints API using AppEngine/Python (not with the Java wizard from Android Studio), then I generated the libs and sources, copied the libs stated in the tutorial to libs/ and extracted the sources.jar file to src/

adding to build.gradle: `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')`

the problem I'm now facing is:

```
08-04 19:40:53.756    2052-2052/com.dgt.ddst E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.google.api.services.dsApi.DsApi$Builder', referenced from method com.dgt.ds.MainActivity$1.doInBackground
08-04 19:40:53.756    2052-2052/com.dgt.ds E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.google.api.services.dsApi.model.ServicesDResponse', referenced from method com.dgt.ds.MainActivity$1.onPostExecute
```

I searched for solutions and all I could find are things related to Eclipse.

how do I fix this in the Android Studio/Gradle environment ?

Comment: Can you expand on what "com.google.api.services.dsApi" is?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it, maybe it is not the best way but I couldn't find a better one:

- First generate your client library for gradle:

  google_appengine/endpointscfg.py get_client_lib java -bs gradle your_module.YourServiceClass
- Uncompress the generated zip file, this will create a folder call your_module
- In Android Studio load the Android app you want to work with your endpoints module
- Go to File -> Project Structure. Add a new module selecting "Import existing project". Point the source folder to your_module folder and then press finish.
- Android Studio will go back to the Project Structure window, select your Android app module and go to the dependencies tab. Add a new "Module dependency" and select your_module.
- Re-sync gradle and rebuild your project and that's all!